# Additional Functions for Window Functions

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, analytic-functions

Thank you so much for the window functions!!!

I'm curious if some more "basic" aggregates will be supported:

```
Sum()
Average()
Min()
Max()
```

Current result of trying to use Sum():

`Error: Unrecognized Analytic Function: SUM cannot be used with an OVER() clause.`

Answer (score 0):

These are currently on the feature roadmap, but we do not have an ETA at this time. Anyone interested in these functions should vote up this question, and we'll use that to prioritize the feature request.

Comment: Note SUM(), COUNT(), COUNT(*), and FIRST_VALUE() have been implemented and will likely be available soon after internal testing. I will ping this thread once they are live.